# Apache Camel multiple filter / selector with operator

Tags: filter, header, apache-camel, selector, operator-keyword

I am trying to filter a message from activeMQ in my Camel Route using filters but I can't make it work when I use operators such as || or &&

So basically I am receiving a message from activemq with several headers, I want my route to filter messages by headers value. But for some headers I want to accept different values, so I need to use something like "header('myHeader' = 'value1' || 'value2')" but it doesn't work.

I tried with filter(), choice().when() and some Simple() code nothing works.

Here is my Route's code (just the filtering part) :

```
// first try                        
.filter(header("CACT").isEqualTo("OBS"))
.filter(header("CDPO").in("SAT", "LYO"))
.filter(header("CDDO").isEqualTo("OBSDOM"))
.filter(header("NAME").isEqualTo("SORSTK"))
.filter(header("FLUX").isNull() || header("FLUX").isEqualTo("SCICS"))

// second try           
.choice()
    .when(header("CACT").isEqualTo("OBS") && 
          header("CDPO").in("SAT", "LYO") && 
          header("CDDO").isEqualTo("OBSDOM") && 
          header("NAME").isEqualTo("SORSTK") &&
          (header("FLUX").isNull() || header("FLUX").isEqualTo("SCICS"))

// third try
.filter().simple('''${in.header[CACT]} == ("OBS") && 
                    ${in.header[CDPO]} == ("LYO" || "SAT") &&
                    ${in.header[CDDO]} == ("OBSDOM") &&
                    ${in.header[NAME]} == ("SORSTK") &&
                    (${in.header[FLUX]} != (null) || ${in.header[FLUX]} == "SAT") ''')
```

I tried those three solutions but none of them works. When I remove the lines that have the || operator, it works. So I don't know how to handle that.
I just want to consume my message if those conditions are verified.

If you have any idea why it doesn't work, your help will be appreciate.

Regards,
Sami

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question, and honestly I dont know how Apache Camel worked 8 years ago. But maybe it could be useful for others.

You can create a custom Predicate by implementing org.apache.camel.Predicate, something like this:

```
public class CustomPredicate implements Predicate {
@Override
public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
    // your logic to decide the return value (true/false)
    return false;
}}
```

And use an instance of this class

```
.filter(customPredicateInstance)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found a solution, I used filter() and simple(), but with no more than 2 conditions pers lines, and I used "and" and "or" instead of "&&" and "||".
Here is the working code :

```
.filter(simple('''${header.CACT} == "OBS"'''))
.filter(simple('''${header.CDPO} == "SAT" or ${header.CDPO} == "LYO"'''))
.filter(simple('''${header.CDDO} == "OBSDOM" and ${header.NAME} == "SORSTK"'''))
.filter(simple('''${header.FLUX} == null or ${header.FLUX} == "SCICS"'''))
```

I'm still interested if you have other suggestions.
Thanks.